# Wordpress Content Security Policy

Tags: wordpress, https

I am completely stumped. We designed a website a few months ago using paperio premium theme and also made use of slider revolution and visual bakery to set up the content. We used All in one seo for optimization. We used All in one security and wordfence to block hacks and spam.

The site ran beautifully for three months without any issues. Yesterday however a number of strange issues popped up. If you view the domains code in the chrome inspector you will notice a long list of errors -

Examples:

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton%3A400 (“default-src https://www.wowflight.co.za”).

Can anyone please give me some direction in how to resolve these problems? It's gotta be something simple, but i can not see where the problem is happening.

Thanks Greg

Answer (score 0):

In the content of the page you have:

> < meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">

It's probably added manually or from a security plugin.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Do i simply delete that line? it's strange how this would break the site now when it was working? Do you think it was added manually?

Comment: I deleted that line of code - it was hard coded into the header. Very strange indeed. The sites working 100% now.

Comment: CSP adds a layer of security by limiting the capabilities of the webpage. It protect against XSS. But if the rules are too strict they can breaks the application. Maybe the rules were good but after the update they were too strict for the new version.

Comment: Thanks for the help and answers. I will keep this in mind for other sites in future.

Comment: where is the location of the file so that we can add these custom meta tags?

Comment: If your site was working previously with CSP, then all of a sudden stopped working, then I would first ask whether you updated plugins just before the break. With an update, a plugin could introduce some new feature which may be well-designed and well-intentioned, but conflicts with CSP. Just another reason to be that more thorough with back-ups and testing on each round of plugin updates; something that you should be doing anyways regardless of CSP.